# How do I deploy a folder using Visual Studio Deployment Product

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2005

I have a reporting tool written in VB. I have added a deployment project to my solution. One of the things I wish to deploy is a folder full of sub folders and files. How can I deploy this using the project please. I seem to be able to add files, project output and assembly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to right click your deployment project in solution explorer, and then select **View>File System**

You'll then see "File system on target machine"

You'd be interested in the "Application Folder" group, there you can add folder and then files within from your project or output

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with the installation package, you have an option for "Application Directory", which is the directory that the content goes.  You can create folders there and they will be created on the users PC as it installs.